# sql query works sometime, and at other times doesn't

Tags: php, mysql

I set up a enable/disable button in an admin panel

http://brettadamsga.com/development/madisonweddings/admin/clients.php

The buttons work sometimes, and then at other times don't, I have no idea what could cause this. Any ideas?

Creates the list of clients

```
<?php
    dbcon();
    $navQuery = 'SELECT * FROM mw_clients WHERE status = 1';
    $li = mysql_query($navQuery);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($li){
        echo "<tr><td><a href=\"index.php?loc=" . $row['clientSlug'] . "\">" . $row['name'] . "</a></td><td align=\"center\"><a style=\"text-decoration: none;\" href=\"changeStatus.php?type=2&id=" . $row['id'] . "&status=0\">&#10005;</a></td></tr>";
    }
?>
```

changeStatus.php

```
<?php
require ('../common.php');

$type=$_GET["type"];
$id=$_GET["id"];
$status=$_GET["status"];

if ($status == 0 && $type == 1)
    {
        dbcon();
        $query = "UPDATE mw_cats SET status=0 WHERE id=" . $id . "";
        if (mysql_query($query))
            {
                echo mysql_error();
                mysql_close();
                header ('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
                header ('Location: categories.php');
            } else {
                echo '<p>Could not change status</p>';
            }
    }

if ($status == 1 && $type == 1)
    {
        dbcon();
        $query = "UPDATE mw_cats SET status=1 WHERE id=" . $id . "";
        if (mysql_query($query))
            {
                echo mysql_error();
                mysql_close();
                header ('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
                header ('Location: categories.php');
            } else {
                echo '<p>Could not change status</p>';
            }
    }

if ($status == 0 && $type == 2)
    {
        dbcon();
        $query = "UPDATE mw_clients SET status=0 WHERE id=" . $id . "";
        if (mysql_query($query))
            {
                echo mysql_error();
                mysql_close();
                header ('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
                header ('Location: clients.php');
            } else {
                echo '<p>Could not change status</p>';
            }
    }

if ($status == 1 && $type == 2)
    {
        dbcon();
        $query = "UPDATE mw_clients SET status=1 WHERE id=" . $id . "";
        if (mysql_query($query))
            {
                echo mysql_error();
                mysql_close();
                header ('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
                header ('Location: clients.php');
            } else {
                echo '<p>Could not change status</p>';
            }
    }

?>
```

Comment: `$_GET` returns a string and your checking for a number

Comment: what would be a good way to turn the string to a number, and if that is the problem then why does it work sometimes?

Comment: The beautiful/ugly thing about PHP is it isn't strongly typed so you can successfully compare "1" to 1, "" to 0, or "0" to 0... (And OP did state that it works sometimes.)

Comment: @JYelton agreed - it just looks untidy - i didnt say it would fix the problem :-) .... my answer would help though .... at least to identify the issue

Comment: @JYelton is right but it would still be a good idea to change your processing of the request vars to use intval() or similar - `$type = intval($_GET['type']);`

Comment: I ended up cleaning up my code, adding some security to it, as well as removing the redirects. After all of this, it started working properly. I am assuming it is the redirects, as I went back and looked, and the 301 redirects are cached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is being caused by your permanent redirects. They get cached by the browser so the next time you access it goes direct to the redirected page instead of running the script.

Answer (score 0):

I find it unusual that you are echoing `mysql_error` when `mysql_query` returns true (success) but not if it fails.

Try moving `mysql_error` to the second part of your if statement, when `mysql_query` returns false.

**Edit:**

Per your comments, here are some more suggestions.

Put some troubleshooting statements in your code. Without a debugger or a way to step through code, a few echo statements can be invaluable in determining what's happening. For example, before the first `if` statement, add:

```
echo 'Status: ' . $status . '<br />';
echo 'Type: ' . $type . '<br />';
```

or better:

```
var_dump($_GET);
```

to find out what's coming through the $_GET array.

Assuming that's working, next make sure your connection is successful:

```
dbcon() or die(mysql_error());
```

(You'll probably have to edit your dbcon() method so that the chance to catch the error is at the actual attempt to connect, your dbcon() method will have to return a boolean false upon failure in order for `or die` to work properly.)

Next, ensure your query is being constructed as you want. Another echo statement can help:

```
echo 'Query: ' . $query . '<br />';
```

Does this query look correct each time? If so, try executing the query as-is in your mysql manager of choice ([Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/), [Sqlyog](http://code.google.com/p/sqlyog/), etc.). This way you can determine if your database is generating an error or taking an unusually long time to execute the query.

If everything seems to be working *still* then you should do some digging in your table to see if the data you are changing is actually changing. Maybe there's a permission problem or something (though that should show up in `mysql_error`.)

```
SELECT id, status FROM mw_cats WHERE id = x;
```

Hopefully one of these suggestions helps!

Comment: I was trying to see if I had a error returning when it was only working sometimes

Comment: I originally had it in the false, but had just moved it when I became frustrated.

Comment: Give us a better idea of what happens when it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: The client, or category stays either enabled or disabled, its status doesn't adjust as it is supposed to. Like I said sometimes it will work, and I can do a few, then it will stop working, and wil not work, then if I wait a little while I can come back and it will start working again.

Comment: I've added additional suggestions to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could remove all of that duplication by replacing your entire code with :

```
require ('../common.php');

$type = $_GET["type"];
$id = $_GET["id"];
$status = $_GET["status"];

dbcon();

$table = "mw_clients";
if ($type == "1") {
    $table = "mw_cats";
}

$query = "UPDATE ".$table." SET status=".mysql_real_escape_string($status)." WHERE id=" . mysql_real_escape_string($id) . "";
if (mysql_query($query))
{
    header ('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
    header ('Location: clients.php');
} else {
    echo '<p>Could not change status '. mysql_error() .'</p>';
}
```

also added [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://uk.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) for security (anyone could call this script in a browser and do things to your DB) and checking for `$type` as a `string` instead of a `number`.

I have no idea why its failing - but now you have some actual error checking (moving the `mysql_error()`) so it should be easier to debug